# Unable to call token contract function from another contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I am having a ERC20 token contract and another test contract which will trigger transfer function on token contract. I am getting a transaction receipt but transfer is not happening in the token contract. This my code

```
import "./ERC20Token.sol";
Contract Test {
  function Test() {
  }

  function triggerTransfer(address tokenAddress, address to, uint value) {
      ERC20Token tok = ERC20Token(tokenAddress);
      tok.transfer(to, value);
  }
```

}

Comment: In the receipt, does gasUsed equal the gas provided?  If so, you're running Out of Gas and increasing the transaction's gas will usually help when the code and logic are correct. EDIT: But not in this case since it is a logic error as answered by @Ismael.

Comment: Yes the gas equals to the gas provided. If increased also same thing happens if I increased more getting an error exceeds block gas limit.

Comment: There's a good chance that this is due to a modifier / conditional statement failing. Check to make sure that the address that you are trying to transfer the tokens from does have the balance you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you are making the transfer from a solidity `Test` contract, and the token will see `Test` as the `msg.sender` and not your user.

In order to make the test work, you have to assign some tokens to the `Test` contract before the it is run.